# Use SimpleXml in php to add additional data into element and save

Tags: php, xml, regex, simplexml

I am using simplexml to load an API URL in the form of an XML through php.  In the `ProductDescription` element it contains html that I would like to append onto in the warranty section.
I would like to add `<li>Valid in US</li>` in the `ProductDescription` element before the LAST `</ul>` tag:

```
    <xmldata>
      <Products>
        <ProductCode>ACODE</ProductCode>
        <ProductID>1234</ProductID>
        <ProductName>PRODUCTTITLE</ProductName>
        <ProductDescription>
           <h1>Stuff</h1><p>description</p><hr /><strong>Features &amp; Benefits</strong>
           <ul><li>feat</li><li>feat</li><li>feat</li></ul><hr /><strong>Specifications</strong><ul><li>spec</li><li>spec</li><li>spec</li></ul> <hr /><strong>Warranty Information for a certain product</strong>
           <ul><li>3 Years Parts</li><li>3 Years Labor</li></ul><div> <a href="/ahref" target="_blank">See more products from MFG </a></div>
        </ProductDescription>
        <ProductManufacturer>MFG</ProductManufacturer>
      </Products>
    </xmldata>
```

Now all I can do is get the bare code out of the ProductDescription, I need to know of a way to add that `list` tag to end of the last `ul` tag before posting or displaying.  Here is my partial php:

```
     foreach( $xml as $NEW_XML ) 
        {          
            $code = $NEW_XML->ProductCode;
            $name = $NEW_XML->ProductName;
            $desc = $NEW_XML->ProductDescription; 
            $mfg = $NEW_XML->ProductManufacturer;
echo "<textarea rows='13' cols='64' name='DESC' />" . $desc. "</textarea>"; }
```

I am hoping I dont have to use REGex as it could be a pain (unless someone knows of a way).  My inital thoughts would be to put it into a `<textarea>` and simply posting it back to an xml, but if there is a way to get to save as an .xml directly that would be more effiecient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of `ul`s is known, you can add the information like this:

```
$NEW_XML->ProductDescription->ul[2]->addChild('li', 'Valid in US');
```

This assumes that `$NEW_XML` is pointing at the `Products`-Element. To *always* get the last `ul` you have to count them first:

```
$desc = $NEW_XML->ProductDescription;
$count = count($desc->ul);
$desc->ul[$count - 1]->addChild('li', 'Valid in US');
```

Then you can just output or save `$xml->asXML()`.

**Update**:

Here is the complete code I used, updated according to my assumption from my last comment, maybe this helps:

```
<?php
$xmldata = <<<ENDXML
<xmldata>
      <Products>
        <Product>
            <ProductCode>ACODE</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>1234</ProductID>
            <ProductName>PRODUCTTITLE</ProductName>
            <ProductDescription>
               <h1>Stuff</h1><p>description</p><hr /><strong>Features &amp; Benefits</strong>
               <ul><li>feat</li><li>feat</li><li>feat</li></ul><hr />    <strong>Specifications</strong><ul><li>spec</li><li>spec</li><li>spec</li></ul> <hr /><strong>Warranty Information for a certain product</strong>
               <ul><li>3 Years Parts</li><li>3 Years Labor</li></ul><div> <a href="/ahref" target="_blank">See more products from MFG </a></div>
            </ProductDescription>
            <ProductManufacturer>MFG</ProductManufacturer>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProductCode>ANOTHERCODE</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>98765</ProductID>
            <ProductName>PRODUCTTITLE 2</ProductName>
            <ProductDescription>
               <h1>Stuff</h1><p>description</p><hr /><strong>Features &amp; Benefits</strong>
               <ul><li>feat</li><li>feat</li><li>feat</li></ul><hr /> <strong>Specifications</strong><ul><li>spec</li><li>spec</li><li>spec</li></ul> <hr /> <strong>Warranty Information for a certain product</strong>
               <ul><li>3 Years Parts</li><li>3 Years Labor</li></ul><div> <a href="/ahref" target="_blank">See more products from MFG </a></div>
            </ProductDescription>
            <ProductManufacturer>MFG</ProductManufacturer>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</xmldata>
ENDXML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmldata);

foreach ($xml->Products->Product as $product) {
    $description = $product->ProductDescription;
    $count = count($description->ul);
    $description->ul[$count-1]->addChild('li', 'Valid in US');
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Its not working.  Is it because I am using `$xml= simplexml_load_file($feedURL)` ?

Comment: Strange, I tested it. What does `echo $NEW_XML->asXML();` in your loop output?

Comment: it `echo's` absolutley nothing, its blank.  I believe its because everything in `ProductDescription` is read as like text not as `Child` Elements.

Comment: If the XML you posted is just like that and the tags are not escaped (like `&gt;ul>`), SimpleXML does read it in as child elements. But rereading the XML something occurs to me: Are you sure that the `ProductCode` and other elements are direct children of `Products`? It would be more logical to have a list of `Product`-Elements in there.